# How to detect if my out going call of whatsapp/telegram/messenger was answered?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Does anybody have any idea how to detect outgoing call is picked up (Answered) and ended or not answered, perhaps by using broadcastReceiver ?

Comment: How are you making an outgoing call?. Are you using any Messagin Service like Firebase or OneSignal to send some details about the caller?

Comment: i'm trying to create a services which alert  user when his outGoing call is picked and i'm not using any messaging services like firebase or OneSignal

Comment: Oh you want to track other app's Broadcast Receiver. For that, there's no way you can do it.

Comment: would u please explain why i can not able to  track other app's Broadcast Receiver?